# Building a general numpy array index dynamically

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

## Basic Background

I am working on some code to simplify training SVMs for data with varying numbers of features, and visualizing the decision boundaries of these SVMs using "slices" specified by the user. If I have `n` features in my data set and `m` samples, I generate an `(n+1)-dimensional` meshgrid where each slice along the first index is an `m x m x ...` mesh of dimension `n`. I can then use my SVM to classify each data point in my meshgrid.

What I want to do next is plot a slice of these results in any two dimensions specified by the user. I have code that plots what I want when the data only has two features, but as soon as I add a third I start running into indexing problems.

## Problem Statement

Say I have a three-dimensional matrix, `predictions`, and I want to plot these predictions over all of the values in my meshgrid `mesh` associated with `index0=0` and `index1=1`, as well as the training data in those dimensions. I can do this with a function call like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.contourf(mesh[index0,:,:,0], mesh[index1,:,:,0], pred[:,:,0])
plt.scatter(samples[:,index0], samples[:,index1], c=labels)
plt.show()
```

What I want to know is how I can build my indexing arrays dynamically so that if `index0=0` and `index1=1`, we get the above code, but if `index0=1` and `index1=2`, we would get:

```
plt.contourf(mesh[index0,0,:,:], mesh[index1,0,:,:], pred[0,:,:])
```

and if `index0=0` and `index1=2`, we would get:

```
plt.contourf(mesh[index0,:,0,:], mesh[index1,:,0,:], pred[:,0,:])
```

How can I go about building these dynamically? Is there a better way to go about this in general for cases where I may not know ahead of time how many features the data is going to have?

## More Details

I attempted something like:

```
mesh_indices0 = [0]*len(mesh.shape)
mesh_indices0[0] = index0
mesh_indices0[index0+1] = ':'    # syntax error: I cannot add this dynamically
mesh_indices0[index1+1] = ':'    # same problem
```

I also tried going at it from the opposite direction with `mesh_indices = [:]*len(mesh.shape)`, but that is invalid syntax as well. I thought about trying something like:

```
mesh_indices[index0+1] = np.r_[:len(samples[:, 1])]
```

where `samples` is my `m x n` set of observations. This seemed really clunky to me though, so I figured there had to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to manipulate slices, you should use the python `slice` object:

```
mesh[index0,0,:,:]
```

is equivalent to:

```
mesh[index0,0,slice(0,mesh.shape[2]),slice(0,mesh.shape[3])]
```

Also note that you can index with a list or tuple of slices and indices:

```
inds = (index0, 0, slice(0,mesh.shape[2]), slice(0,mesh.shape[3]))
mesh[inds]
```

Putting it all together, you can make a list of `:`-equivalent `slice` objects, then replace the appropriate one with your concrete index. Or, go the other way:

```
mesh_indices = [0]*len(mesh.shape)
mesh_indices[0] = index0
mesh_indices[index0+1] = slice(0, mesh.shape[index0+1])
mesh_indices[index1+1] = slice(0, mesh.shape[index1+1])
```

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I want it to. Thank you so much!